# SQL Server file and filegroup, creating order

Tags: sql-server, file, filegroup

When it comes to files and filegroups, I want to create a secondary filegroup, so I should create a secondary file first, then create a user-defined filegroup, or I should create a user-defined filegroup first, then create a secondary file? What is the best practice for this?

Answer (score 0):

Files are created and exist within a specific filegroup.  They cannot be moved, so you must create the filegroup first.

Comment: So, When I create a new database, there are primary data files and log files that existed there already, I have to add a secondary filegroup first, then I add a secondary file and click point it to the user-defined filegroup, lastly, set this user-defined filegroup as default?